# Firebase auth: Error getting access token from GOOGLE_OIDC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, firebase

I have two Firebase projects, with one I can login using Google auth, no problem. But the other gives me this error. I can't find any difference in settings between the two. With both, I'm running the project and logging in from localhost.

```
Error getting access token from GOOGLE_OIDC, request is: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=385081226950-opume6j1nqt3rk9einrdjldpqnhvkjcl.apps.googleusercontent.com&code=4/1gDYKHBbne2u_R9AAl6lzumwLPRn2EdmfMWQmpKI8nt4SoglhG9ov1uBGDagvMFwQhUAqzYXp8yeQCNAemqjVEI&redirect_uri=https://stokebrain-local.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response is: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client&error_description=Unauthorized, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=401, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDuration=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

, cookieList=[]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, solved finally.

Go to Firebase console:
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/-your-project-id-/authentication/providers

```
Sign-in Method -> Google -> Edit (pencil icon) -> Web client secret
```

For me, Web client secret was wrong. Above, next to "Web SDK configuration", mouse over info icon, click the link for "Google API Console". Near the top of this page you'll find the Web client secret, copy and paste into Firebase. Auth should now work.

Comment: Life saver! I spent a few hours trying to figure out to no avail what was going wrong until I found your post!